# How to use Phusion Passenger Standalone as the default Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

Due to some fancy tricks in my Rails app (and in the interest of making my dev setup look more like prod) I've started using [Phusion Passenger Standalone](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Standalone.html) as my development web server.

Currently I start it as `$ bundle exec passenger start`.  If I run `$ rails s` it boots WEBrick, which is not what I want.

**Is there a way to configure my app so I can run it the "usual way" as `$ rails s`?**

(Sorry if this is obvious, searching for the expected keywords on Google finds a lot of unrelated stuff...)

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to force this, there's an easy hack that will do exactly what you want.
You can modify your application's script/rails to catch all rails server calls and make a system call to start passenger, like so:

```
if (ARGV.first == 'server' || ARGV.first == 's')
  system("passenger start #{ARGV.shift.join(" ")}")
else
  # The old content of the script goes here
  APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
  require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',  __FILE__)
  require 'rails/commands'
end
```

for more info check here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phusion-passenger/XBhlF5lRo2A

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But one suggestion: instead of `ARGV.shift` I ended up using `ARGV.drop(1)` in order to pass to passenger all arguments but the first one.